# R cannot be resolved to a variable - App compact

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but I have been receiving this error since a while and I think it is directly related to the following library:
android-support-v7-appcompact

I have linked this library to my current project, and has been experiencing issue ever since. I have tried doing project clean, but I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: Without code will be hard to get any help. Also you might have some error on your XML and R can't be generated because of that.

Comment: the problem is that I recieve the following error in practically every activity R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Because R is a single file. Of course you will get that error on all activities. Check all your XML files for possible errors.

Comment: what is the target sdk version?

Comment: thank you for your responses. target on both android-support-v7-appcompat and the current project is target=android-21

Comment: no, change it from 2.1 to the latest you have. It will still run on 2.1 as you have the v7-appcompact

Comment: thanks for your response. both android-support-v7 and my project have the same target - target=android-21

Comment: yes, you are supposed to change the build target version in your project. andriod-support-v7 target remains the same.

Comment: Hi, I am using eclipse as my IDE, and maybe this error can help a bit - error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'. (in the themebar.xml)

Comment: Try to close and reopen your project. Eclipse sucks sometimes.